# Does an activity become paused before calling onPause()?

Tags: android

Does an activity become paused before calling method onPause()? Google reference says that when an activity is paused, it can be killed by the system in extreme low memory situations.It also syas that we should commit unsaved changes in onPause().So I guess the activity goes into paused state after calling onPause().But I don't know how to prove it.
So I wonder whether is ture?Is there a method which can return the current state of activity?

Comment: what you want from us?

Comment: Well, they seems to tell it [in the lyfecyle guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onpause)

Comment: See this link https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity paused from `Instrumentation` class from `callActivityOnPause` method:

```
/**
 * Perform calling of an activity's {@link Activity#onPause} method.  The
 * default implementation simply calls through to that method.
 * 
 * @param activity The activity being paused.
 */
public void callActivityOnPause(Activity activity) {
    activity.performPause();
}
```

It just calls `Activity`'s `performPause` method:

```
final void performPause() {
    mDoReportFullyDrawn = false;
    mFragments.dispatchPause();
    mCalled = false;
    onPause();
    mResumed = false;
    if (!mCalled && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion
            >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        throw new SuperNotCalledException(
                "Activity " + mComponent.toShortString() +
                " did not call through to super.onPause()");
    }
    mResumed = false;
}
```

As you can see, `onPause` is called inside `performPause`, so you are right:

> activity goes into paused state after calling onPause().

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand why google advise us to commit changes in onPause() since the activity in paused mode can be killed. Because the activity is not paused until onPause() method returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can find in the official documentation of android lifecycle https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html :

"onPause" is Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going into the background, but has not (yet) been killed. The counterpart to onResume().

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.v(TAG, "onPause is called");
}
```

Comment: You should edit your answer to point out the source of the first line since this is from the official documentation ;) This is better since this is not a simple sentence you have invented

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can add some variable to check the state of your Activity.
Create a `boolean isPaused` which becomes true `onPause`, false `onResume` etc. 
Do the same foe each state you want to check.
In any case I don't see a reason not to believe the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

onPause is called before the activity is paused.

When an Activity goes into paused mode, it still can be shown to the user! so when the activity is stopped (onStop) it is no longer visible to the user.

What exactly do you want to prove?